# append rows with if statement in for loop to a dataframe using python with very large files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

After updating anaconda-navigator, I am receiving this message on a code I wrote:

**'The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.'**

I'm conducting an artificial star experiment and using three files. I have included the first 15 rows of each:

*artificial stars with b-filter*

```
b1:
    Id       x         y      bmag    z1  z2  z3  z4  z5
      1    1163.630 1327.069  16.4552   0   0   0   0   0
      2    1747.045 1477.734  16.1293   0   0   0   0   0
      3    3236.084 1252.050  16.5628   0   0   0   0   0
      4    2516.600  888.832  17.7005   0   0   0   0   0
      5    1868.000 1376.218  16.3139   0   0   0   0   0
      6    2484.642  941.331  16.7632   0   0   0   0   0
      7    2984.336  640.185  16.1351   0   0   0   0   0
      8    2612.480 1664.341  16.3573   0   0   0   0   0
      9    1973.405  731.071  18.7704   0   0   0   0   0
     10    3391.978  130.435  16.1769   0   0   0   0   0
     11     165.021  942.634  17.4829   0   0   0   0   0
     12    2491.430 1397.675  16.5589   0   0   0   0   0
     13    2886.291 1367.745  16.3339   0   0   0   0   0
     14     939.302  726.039  16.8744   0   0   0   0   0
     15    2296.265  686.110  16.1132   0   0   0   0   0
```

*artificial stars with I-filter* (coordinates here are ignored as they are the same as those in b1)

```
i1:
     Id       x         y      imag    z1  z2  z3  z4  z5
      1    1168.121 1332.597  15.1104   0   0   0   0   0
      2    1751.536 1483.263  14.3248   0   0   0   0   0
      3    3240.575 1257.578  15.3140   0   0   0   0   0
      4    2521.091  894.360  17.1246   0   0   0   0   0
      5    1872.491 1381.746  14.8184   0   0   0   0   0
      6    2489.133  946.859  15.6679   0   0   0   0   0
      7    2988.827  645.714  14.3458   0   0   0   0   0
      8    2616.971 1669.869  14.9122   0   0   0   0   0
      9    1977.896  736.599  18.6215   0   0   0   0   0
     10    3396.469  135.964  14.4787   0   0   0   0   0
     11     169.512  948.163  16.8041   0   0   0   0   0
     12    2495.921 1403.203  15.3067   0   0   0   0   0
     13    2890.782 1373.273  14.8621   0   0   0   0   0
     14     943.793  731.567  15.8544   0   0   0   0   0
     15    2300.756  691.638  14.2601   0   0   0   0   0
```

*measured stars*

```
biart:
     Id      x       y      bmag         imag      
      1    3.463   964.699  16.0450     16.9640   
      2    5.084  1567.960  16.9260     18.4700   
      3    5.105   236.018  15.0720     16.1090   
      4    5.236   364.229  17.4830     15.8440   
      5    5.478  1434.603  17.3220     16.7400   
      6    5.564   453.920  16.9000     17.2100   
      7    6.015  1186.374  17.9310     15.5080   
      8    6.017   945.186  17.5790     17.2270   
      9    6.031  1001.720  15.4920     16.7710   
     10    6.337   747.211  16.0480     14.9890   
     11    6.376  1243.525  15.8780     14.8180   
     12    6.426   635.425  17.3890     17.2010   
     13    6.432    72.437  16.3430     16.7180   
     14    6.584   982.933  17.7750     17.9360   
     15    6.630   688.179  16.8100     17.2390
```

**I have written a code to calculate the minimum radial distance between stars in b1 (artificial) and biart (measured) that I have been working with.**

**The code goes through each row of b1 and determines which row of biart has minimum distance as specified by the if statement**

**Each row that satisfies the constrain is written in a dataframe using df.append() with the 'Id', 'x_art', 'y_art', 'bmag' from b1, 'imag' from i1 and 'Id', 'x_meas', 'y_meas', 'bmag', 'imag' from biart.**

**The running time for the files with 7000 to 35000 stars is at most 132 seconds for the code below**

```
extract = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Id_art', 'x_art', 'y_art', 
                                'bmag_art', 'imag_art', 
                                'dist_d',
                                'Id_meas', 'x_meas', 'y_meas',                                 
                                'bmag_meas', 'imag_meas'])
start = time.time()

for i in range(len(b1.index)):
    
    x = b1['x'].iloc[i]
    y = b1['y'].iloc[i]
    
    dist = np.sqrt((x - biart['x'])**2 + (y - biart['y'])**2)
    
    if (min(dist))<=1/2:
            
        extract = extract.append({'Id_art': b1['Id'].iloc[i],
                                    'x_art':b1['x'].iloc[i], 
                                   'y_art': b1['y'].iloc[i], 
                                 'bmag_art':b1['bmag'].iloc[i],
                                 'imag_art':i1['imag'].iloc[i],
                                      'dist_d':min(dist), 
                            'Id_meas':biart['Id'].iloc[dist.idxmin()], 
                             'x_meas':biart['x'].iloc[dist.idxmin()],
                             'y_meas':biart['y'].iloc[dist.idxmin()], 
                          'bmag_meas':biart['bmag'].iloc[dist.idxmin()],
                          'imag_meas':biart['imag'].iloc[dist.idxmin()]},
                                     ignore_index=True)

print('extracting done! Duration: {} seconds'.format(time.time()-start))

extracting done! Duration: 132.52907395362854 seconds
```

**This is the output example of smaller files**
[image: output]

**Rewriting the code using lists and pd.concat() instead of df.append()
took 40 minutes.**

```
start = time.time()

list_a = []

for i in range(len(b1.index)):
    
    x = b1['x'].iloc[i]
    y = b1['y'].iloc[i]

    dist = np.sqrt((x - biart['x'])**2 + (y - biart['y'])**2)

    if (min(dist))<=1/2:
        
        list_a.append(pd.DataFrame({'Id_art': b1['Id'].iloc[i],
             'x_art':b1['x'].iloc[i], 
             'y_art': b1['y'].iloc[i], 
             'bmag_art':b1['bmag'].iloc[i],
             'imag_art':i1['imag'].iloc[i],
             'dist_d':min(dist), 
             'Id_meas':biart['Id'].iloc[dist.idxmin()], 
             'x_meas':biart['x'].iloc[dist.idxmin()],
             'y_meas':biart['y'].iloc[dist.idxmin()], 
             'bmag_meas':biart['bmag'].iloc[dist.idxmin()],
             'imag_meas':biart['imag'].iloc[dist.idxmin()]}, index=[0]))       
        
        extract = pd.concat(list_a, ignore_index=True)

del list_a

print('extracting done! Duration: {} seconds'.format(time.time()-start))

extracting done! Duration: 2364.3006489276886 seconds
```

**I am new to python and appreciate your help. Is there a more efficient and faster way to obtain the same results as my original code?**

Comment: extract = pd.concat(list_a, ignore_index=True) must be out of loop. Execute only one time

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more vectorized way to do what you've described in your question:

```py
start = time.time()

distThreshold = 2000
def getIdxWithMinDist(row):
    dist = np.sqrt((row.x - biart.x)**2 + (row.y - biart.y)**2)
    idxMn = dist.idxmin()
    return biart.loc[idxMn].Id if dist[idxMn] <= distThreshold else None
b1['id_of_closest_biart'] = b1.apply(getIdxWithMinDist, axis=1)
extract = b1.loc[b1.id_of_closest_biart.notna(),[
    'id_of_closest_biart', 'Id','x','y','bmag']].assign(imag=i1.imag)
extract.id_of_closest_biart = extract.id_of_closest_biart.astype(int)
extract = extract.merge(biart, how='left', left_on='id_of_closest_biart', right_on='Id', suffixes=(
    '_art', '_meas')).drop(columns='id_of_closest_biart')

print('extracting done! Duration: {} seconds'.format(time.time()-start))
print(extract)
```

Output:

```
extracting done! Duration: 0.016347169876098633 seconds
   Id_art     x_art     y_art  bmag_art  imag_art  Id_meas  x_meas    y_meas  bmag_meas  imag_meas
0       1  1163.630  1327.069   16.4552   15.1104       11   6.376  1243.525     15.878     14.818
1       2  1747.045  1477.734   16.1293   14.3248        5   5.478  1434.603     17.322     16.740
2       5  1868.000  1376.218   16.3139   14.8184        5   5.478  1434.603     17.322     16.740
3       9  1973.405   731.071   18.7704   18.6215       10   6.337   747.211     16.048     14.989
4      11   165.021   942.634   17.4829   16.8041        8   6.017   945.186     17.579     17.227
5      14   939.302   726.039   16.8744   15.8544       10   6.337   747.211     16.048     14.989
```

Note that I have set the threshold to 2000 instead of 1/2, since 1/2 had no matches for your sample input.

Explanation:

- Use `apply()` to populate a new column in `b1` which holds the `Id` value of the row in `biart` which has the minimum distance from that row of `b1`, if any such row is found with a minimum distance <= to our threshold
- Initialize `extract` to contain a subset of the columns in `b1` as well as the `imag` column from `i1`, but only for the rows that satisfied the minimum distance constraint
- Use `merge()` to add to `b1` the desired columns in `biart` for the rows we identified above; use suffixes on column labels from each dataframe to distinguish `b1` columns from `biart` columns
- Use `drop()` to eliminate the intermediate column (`id_of_closest_biart`) used for the merge.

Comment: Do you need any additional help with your question?